# Load WPF assembly from console application

Tags: wpf, reflection, .net-assembly, .net-core-3.1

How can I load a *WPF User Control Library* dynamically from a console application?

**Problem description:**

I have an assembly that is compiled as *WPF User Control Library* and want to load it from a console application using reflection. Unfortunately, I receive a `System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException` with this message:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Loading "normal" *Class Library* assemblies works without problems. Even if they have dependencies, everything is loaded correctly. However, loading fails as soon as the assembly contains WPF.

**What I tried:**

I tried different ways to load the assembly, but all of them fail with above exception:

1. Using `System.ComponentModel.Composition` with imports and exports.
2. Using `Assembly.LoadFrom()`.
3. Using a custom `AssemblyLoadContext` as described at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support).

I made sure that the path to the assembly is correct. If I specify invalid paths, the error message is different.

**Details:**

The assembly has target framework *.NET Core 3.1* and output type *Class Library*. It uses the *Microsoft.NETCore.App* and the *Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF* frameworks.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The console application has target framework *.NET Core 3.1* and output type *Console Application*. It uses the *Microsoft.NETCore.App* framework.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Have you tried also referencing PresentationFramework.dll in your console app besides your WPF library?

Comment: No, I havent. I dont want to do this, because the console application should not need to know about the dependencies of the assembly.

Comment: @pschill: Did you look at the plugin examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/extensions/AppWithPlugin)?

Comment: @mm8 Yes, I did. The plugin examples repository contains the code of the [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support) article that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @pschill: You need to load the WPF assemblies from the SDK.

Comment: @mm8 I understand. But why wont the loader find them automatically? It does find the other runtime assemblies after all. Where can I find the SDK assemblies? And why wont the `dotnet publish` command for my assembly add them to the output directory if they are required?

Comment: @pschill: It finds the ones in the SDK that your app is targeting, i.e. `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`. `dotnet publish` works provided that you add a reference to the WPF library. I thought you were loading the assembly dynamically after you have published the app?